# Wrong style in listitem, not using correct parent

Tags: android, layout, xamarin

I've got a listview with listitems which got badges.

This badge is a TextView with a background.

```
<TextView        
    style="@style/Badge"
    android:id="@+id/badgeTextView"
    android:paddingLeft="3dp"
    android:paddingRight="3dp"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true" />
```

The style has a parent style/theme which decides the colors.

```
<style name="Badge" parent="Theme_X">
   <item name="android:background">@color/c_blue</item>
   <item name="android:textColor">@color/c_white</item>
</style>

<style name="Badge" parent="Theme_Y">
   <item name="android:background">@color/c_black</item>
   <item name="android:textColor">@color/c_white</item>
</style>
```

But the colors from the last Badge style are used.
I've got other parts in the layout which are styled like this, but those don't have this problem.

Is this happenig because it's a list item which might not inherit the theme, and if so, how do I fix this. Or is this caused by something else?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out themes/styles don't work like this. 
I've fixed it by using attributes holding the color:

```
<attr name="badgecolor" format="reference|color" />
<attr name="badgetextcolor" format="reference|color" />
```

And setting these attributes in the theme styles.

```
<style name="Theme_X" parent="Theme_Main">
    <item name="badgecolor">@color/c_black</item>
    <item name="badgetextcolor">@color/c_white</item>
</style>

<style name="Theme_Y" parent="Theme_Main">
    <item name="badgecolor">@color/c_white</item>
    <item name="badgetextcolor">@color/c_black</item>
</style>
```

Then there is just one badge style with variable colors:

```
<style name="Badge">
    <item name="android:background">?badgecolor</item>
    <item name="android:textColor">?badgetextcolor</item>    
</style>
```

That can be used in the axml file:

```
<TextView
    style="@style/Badge" 
    android:id="@+id/badgeTextView"
    android:paddingLeft="3dp"
    android:paddingRight="3dp"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true" />
```